# Gradle: how to check duplicate class in project?

Tags: java, gradle

My application can not run normal when it has duplicate class, with problem like 'no such method'.

The project have two class with the same class name , one is from project code, another is from a jar file. how to check this problem when build the gradle project?

```
src/main/java/com/kxw/Example.java

gradle.build
compile("com.kxw:xxx:1.0")//contain com.kxw.Example
```

I expect there has a gradle plugin can check duplicate class in project, like 'maven enforcer plugin' from maven project.

Comment: A project can have multiple classes with same name but package name can be different. If you want to build, change the package name.

Comment: one is from project code, another is from a jar file (developer do not know).
project build normal but throw exception when run ,how to check to avoid