# how to checks If there exist duplicate class with specified class name in Java Runtime Enviroment?

Tags: java, gradle, classloader

My application can not run normal when it has duplicate class, with problem like 'no such method'.

The project have two class with the same class name , one is from project code, another is from a jar file. how to check this problem when application start up?

```
src/main/java/com/kxw/Example.java

gradle.build
compile("com.kxw:xxx:1.0")//contains com.kxw.Example
```

I expect there has java api or utils to check when application start up .

```
public void startUp(){

     if(existDuplicateClass("com.kxw.Example")){
           shutdown();
     }
}

protected boolean existDuplicateClass(String className){

//TODO
}
```

i don't konw how to implement method existDuplicateClass.

refenence:
[Gradle: how to check duplicate class in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57380320/gradle-how-to-check-duplicate-class-in-project)

Comment: Java really does not have utilities for this.  You shouldn't name your classes the same, that's a disaster.  Packages are namespaces to keep you classes separate, use them.

Comment: if you can not guarantee that your preferred classes will be first in the class path ; you can implement a `version` method in your source code for all such classes that can be duplicated  and manually check them at startup - the code will either pass or fail with methodnotfound exception.

Comment: i agree, how to implement a version method, please give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

finally i check duplicate class when startup by this way :

```
 String classPath = Optional.ofNullable(xx.class.getProtectionDomain())
                    .map(ProtectionDomain::getCodeSource)
                    .map(CodeSource::getLocation)
                    .map(URL::getPath).orElse("");

//class is not from common-core.jar
if (!classPath.contains("common-core")) {
        log.error("{} thrift class may be duplicate ...", xx.class.getName());
        shutdownContext.shutdown();
}
```